# SQL ReportsTo Query

Tags: sql

So I been struggling with this one for a while. The question is as follows:

Find all the Employees to whom no other employee reports to. Print the Id, and the first and last name of such employees.

The Relationship Sets can be found here:

https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Documentation

And the Data in the Table is as follows (Note that the rest of the data that is cut off is not needed)

[image: Table]

Now, the easiest solution that I immediately saw was that the Sale Support had no one report to them:

```
Select DISTINCT E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName    
From Employee E
Where E.Title = 'Sales Support Agent'
```

But that seems like a cheap work around, is there a way to get the answer using EmployeeID and ReportsTo only?

Comment: using that data set what is your desire output? And I dont understand `Employees to whom no other employee reports to`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e585b/2)**

```
 SELECT E.*
 FROM Employee E
 LEFT JOIN Employee R  -- R for report to
   ON E.EmployeeID = R.ReportTo
 WHERE R.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| EmployeeID | LastName | ReportTo |
|------------|----------|----------|
|          3 |  Peacock |        2 |
|          4 |     Park |        2 |
|          5 |  Johnson |        2 |
|          7 |     King |        6 |
|          8 | Callahan |        6 |
```

Comment: HI Juan, to answer your comment above, I am sorry if you felt your answer was more deserving, I am new to SQL so I am not familiar with Left Join, and the answer that i chose as best was easier for me to understand as i knew all the used concepts. Sorry and thanks

Comment: Dont worry. Im not saying the answer is wrong. Just that isnt the best answer for this question. I have to point that out in case someone else came and try to find a similar answer. Also I give you all three option in a fiddle so you can check it later and compare by yourself and maybe learn new things :).

Comment: Also Doolius answer is the same as A. El-Helw and he give it first. So in that case you like that answer better I  think he deserve it more. He maybe give a wrong answer first but then he fix it. And using `distinct` in the inside query can also improve perfomance because is a smaller set to compare.

Comment: Juan, I just voted up your answer because of its better performance. I honestly don't mind whose answer is chosen as the correct one. I'm not here for the points. I'm here to help others, because I also need help sometimes. And as for Doolius' answer, as you pointed out, it was wrong at first, and I'm the one who give him the fix (check the comments). Also, adding the "distinct" clause can add unneeded aggregation. Either way, as I said, I don't care which answer is chosen as long as there is some right answer there. Better yet if there are multiple correct answers. Have a great day!

Comment: Well, the performance is better as Juan has stated. If it;s alright with you then Helw I will change the best answer to this one for the sake of others who may come across this.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you are wanting:

```
Select 
    E.EmployeeId
    ,E.FirstName
    ,E.LastName    
From Employee E
Where E.EmployeeID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ReportsTo
                           FROM Employee
                           WHERE ReportsTo is not null)
```

Selects every employee that has no one who reports to them.

Comment: This will not work because there is a `NULL` value in `reportsTo` - plus the `distinct` is useless in the subquery.

Comment: Easily fixable by adding: WHERE ReportsTo IS NOT NULL inside the subquery

Comment: `reportsTo` is an integer, converting it to a string `''` makes no sense (and will fail with e.g. Postgres)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Select E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName    
From Employee E
Where E.EmployeeID NOT IN (SELECT ReportsTo FROM Employee WHERE ReportsTo IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks works great, could you mind explaining the logic of your third line so I could better understand how it works, Thanks!

Comment: The subquery selects all the values in the "ReportsTo" column that are not NULL. This is a list of all Employees who have someone reporting to them. Then the main query basically selects all employees who are not in that list.

Comment: Why you select this answer as the correct? If you check the fiddles My [**answer**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e585b/2) is faster 3ms, this [**answer**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e585b/21) take 5-6ms. Also instead of  `NOT IN` you should use `NOT EXISTS` for better [**performance**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e585b/20)  4ms. And also my answer was early than this.

Comment: Got it, Thanks! Was able to also reverse to answer by just saying IN makes a lot of sense now.